How to display a single taxonomy value in Wordpress
I have a custom post type called 'Company' and another called 'Testimonial'. Both cpt's use a shared custom taxonomy called 'company_key'. For instance, "Mazda" is a 'Company' and uses the company_key "mazda" (it's simply the slug of the 'Company'). The 'Testimonial' associated with "Mazda" also uses the company_key "mazda". It's my wild attempt to pair content on this site.
The 'Testimonials' appear as cards on the home page. At the bottom of each Testimonial card, there is a link that should point you to the 'Company' rather than to the actual 'Testimonial' itself. I can't do this manually because the cards will be many.
To automate this, all I need to do is create a link that retrieves the value of the Testimonials company_key and adds it to the end of the link. In simple terms, it would look like this:
https://mywebsite.com/company/'company_key'

In this example:
https://mywebsite.com/company/mazda

I tried this (and a million other ways) but can't get it to work as I either get no value or simple the word Array:
$the_btn = '<a href="https://mywebsite.com/company/' . get_term( 'company_key' ) . '">See Company</a>';

I'm completely stuck on this...

OMG that worked! Yeah I had to fiddle around with the snippet a bit to make it work with the rest of my stuff, but that worked!!

Happy to hear it worked! If you wouldn't mind, clicking the check mark to accept the answer would be a huge help. Thanks!

I would if I could believe me, I have no check mark...the only thing I can do is vote a comment as 'useful'...

I posted as a fully comment for having the check mark, Thanks for pointing that

I was going to copy your snippet for another question I posted last night but it looks like your answer has been removed, or am I missing something?

i had to arrange with ai the format and they flagged it as i answered the question with ai. thats why it was removed

echo '' . esc_html($term->name) . '';
but this is the idea inside the loop

$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'company_key');
if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms))
{
$term = array_pop($terms);
echo '' . esc_html($term->name) . '';
}
